# Existing Maven project to Eclipse based dynamic web project

Tags: maven, web

I am not good with Maven project stuff, so I would like to convert it to dynamic web project in Eclipse . This Maven project includes one web project and other sub projects in it  . really no idea how to convert all these supported projects along with the maven web project to convert to Eclipse based dynamic web project .  please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this plugin on your pom

```
        <!-- Maven Eclipse Plugin -->
        <!-- version 2.9 has testSourcesLast flag but does not delete .settings -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

this in your properties: eclipseTomcatServer must match the name of your tomcat in eclipse

```
 <eclipseTomcatServer>Apache Tomcat v7.0</eclipseTomcatServer>
```

and this in your profile

```
<profiles>
    <!-- profile to enable WTP in Eclipse -->
    <profile>
        <id>wtp</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>src/main/webapp</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                       <downloadSources>false</downloadSources>
                       <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                        <!-- WTP version -->
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                        <!-- WTP server -->
                        <wtpdefaultserver>${eclipseTomcatServer}</wtpdefaultserver>
                        <classpathContainers>
                            <!-- Libraries from JRE -->
                            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                            <!-- Libraries from server container -->
                            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/${eclipseTomcatServer}</classpathContainer>
                            <!-- Libraries from META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -->
                            <!-- <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container</classpathContainer> -->
                            <!-- Libraries from WEB-INF/lib -->
                            <!-- <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container</classpathContainer> -->
                            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container/artifact</classpathContainer>
                        </classpathContainers>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <!-- JavaScript support -->
                            <buildcommand>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</buildcommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <!-- JavaScript support -->
                            <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <additionalProjectFacets>
                            <!-- JavaScript support -->
                            <wst.jsdt.web>1.0</wst.jsdt.web>
                        </additionalProjectFacets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

then type the command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

or

```
 mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=[wtp version, usually 2.0 ]
```